# Is there a way to get Flash to accept self-signed certificates for RTMPS NetConnections?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I have a self-signed certificate that validates just fine. When I install the root cert on a client machine, sites served using self-signed certificates work just fine.

However, when I install it in FMS 4.5 and try to connect to it through Flash (in my case the 11.2 debug player running on Windows 7 in Firefox), it gives back a `NetConnection.Connect.CertificateUntrustedSigner` error. It also does pop up a Windows prompt warning that the Certificate Issuer is untrusted or unknown, although it seems that however I respond to the prompt, it has no effect one way or another.

My suspicion is that Flash disregards the OS's installed root certs and maintains its own list. Is that the case? If so, is there any way to use self-signed certs in this case?